# How to build a sinkhole simulation?

Tags: sinkhole

I'm doing a science project on sink holes and I don't have an idea on how to build one. I want to test different methods of creating a sinkhole.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , unfortunately, this is a Home Improvement discussion ant=d the question dies not fit that topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about engineering and geology

Comment: I would at least move it to Earth Science SE.

Comment: (sigh... apologies for the tupohgapicl errrorx.)

Answer (score 1):

I would use sand and experiment with different size openings under different thicknesses of the sand. If you fill a small container with a couple inches of sand and then open a hole on the bottom of the container it should simulate a sink hole.

Start with a funnel full of sand and see if it flows good when you take your finger off the end of it. Maybe try salt or sugar for their flow characteristics.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: That question is way off topic.